# Online Metric Learning for Face Recognition

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, face-recognition, euclidean-distance, mahalanobis

I'm using [OpenFace](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/) to compute representations (in 128D) for faces found in images taken under unconstrained conditions that show significant variations in lighting, time, etc.

According to their website and demos, a standard Euclidean distance with a proper threshold is enough to be able to use these representations for a "same-not same" scheme. That is, given two faces with representations v1 and v2, I can determine whether they belong to the same person if eucDist(v1,v2) < S.

In practice, the results are not bad but definitely far from perfect. What I would like to do in my application, is to use user input to improve the prediction.

Ideally, I would like to carry out something like the following procedure:

- Assume I have extracted N faces, for each I have a representation which is a vector in R^128. Suppose these faces belong to n individuals (when n is significantly smaller than N).
- I choose randomly k faces (when k is a small number, say 10) and display them to the user, asking her to tag these for faces belonging to the same person.
- I now want to use the user input to "tweak" the euclidean distance so that it performs better: Making distance between faces she tagged as "not same"  bigger and distance between faces she tagged as "same" smaller. Obviously, I want to do this in a way that generalizes to the entire data set of N faces.
- "patient" users can keep tagging photos to improve results.

I know this relates to the field of "metric learning" and I have read about things like Mahalanobis distance, but I'm not sure how to put it to work in this "online" scenario. I was wondering if anyone had any experience with such a task and could shed some light or give me any pointers. I should mention that I'm not really looking for too "heavy math"; Ideally, I would like to know if there exists an algorithm (preferably with some existing implementation that I could use) that could improve performance based on user input. For starters I'll be satisfied with any sort of improvement, so it doesn't have to be the best method available.

Thanks!

Comment: A multi-class convolutional neural network with suitably labelled data should be worth trying for this application.

Comment: This sounds like a tough project, especially because it's somehow the task of skipping OpenFace and doing all by some customized algorithm. Are you really using the euclidean distances *directly* to decide if two faces are equal? Normally this step is done by some external classifier like Support-Vector-Machines. Now you could start with inputing your extra.data in this classification step. You are not changing the differences, but the interpretation. I think the SVM-after-face-representation-approach is also the standard way in most of openface's examples!

Comment: I have responded with some thoughts on this mailing list post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cmu-openface/oSXtulfj0cA/SC0hl5_HAAAJ